# Auto-scale setting the window too small GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

I have this code:

```
set title "Ex1.txt"
set key title "Legenda"
set key inside right top vertical Right reverse enhanced autotitle box opaque
set key noinvert samplen 1 spacing 1 width 0 height 0
set style fill  transparent solid 0.50 noborder
set parametric
set trange[0:]
set xrange[0:]
set yrange[0:]
set grid
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'ev.png'
plot [0:][0:] t, -2.0*t+(2000.0) with filledcurves x1, t, -0.6666666666666666*t+(1333.3333333333333) with filledcurves x1, t, -0.8333333333333334*t+(0.0),t, -0.8333333333333334*t+(1333.3333333333333),t, -0.8333333333333334*t+(1416.6666666666667),
unset output
unset terminal
unset parametric
exit
```

But when I run this script the windows, in the x "range", goes from 0 to 5. It really is supposed to start at zero but if it goes only until 5 I can barely distinguish the lines.
Here you can see the output of the code as it is:
[image]

If I change the x scale to [0:700] it goes like this:
[image]

As you can see much better because we can distinguish all lines. The problem is that I can't specify the maximum range because the equations might be different, because this is an output of a java program that I have, for example in this case 700 works but in another exercise the optimal value could be 300. Is there a way to make the gnuplot to know the max range of the x axis without the autoscale as it is (because it stops at x=5)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no autoscaling in xrange or trange for function plots, but only a default range. Because there is no reasonable way to set a default range depending on the function definitions. BTW: you don't need parametric mode for the given plots

Comment: I would rather output the range `[0:tmax]` somehow from the java-script, and pass this as a parameter to gnuplot. Or try to get functions of scaled variables `s=t/tmax` so that they are defined in the range `s=[0:1]`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that.  gnuplot uses a default fixed range for all functions (unless set to another value by a range command), and it has no idea what you might find interesting (do you want to see where the curves intersect, or do you want to see where they intersect the axes - gnuplot wouldn't know), so can't highlight any such features.

Additionally, although it does have some features to analyze curves and such, it is far from being a mathematical workspace, and would have no way to find such interesting points.  gnuplot is designed to graph data, not manipulate it.

If you have to drive this from another program, you are going to have to have that program do the analysis and figure out what range to use.  I have several python programs that use gnuplot to graph data, but the python code figures out what ranges need to be and adds the command to the gnuplot call.